# Difference between single tone and dual tone signals?

Tags: digital-communications

**Editted**

Single tone signal has 1 frequency:
$$ y = \sin(2\cdot \pi \cdot f_1  \cdot t)$$

Dual tone was created by using 2 frequencies:

$$\sin(2\cdot \pi \cdot f_1  \cdot t) + \sin(2\cdot \pi \cdot f_2  \cdot t)$$

How can I define on the plot this difference, whether it is a single tone signal or not?

Comment: well, now that you've changed the formulas, hasn't the question answered itself?

Answer (score 2):

It's either, depending how we look at it:

$$
\sin(f_1t) + \sin(f_2t) = 2 \cos(.5(f_1 - f_2)t)\sin(.5(f_1 + f_2)t) \tag{1}
$$

A common empirical rule is that if $f_1 \ll f_2$ (e.g. $f_2 / f_1 > 5$), consider them separate - else, a single amplitude-modulated tone, where $(f_1+f_2)$ is the "carrier" and $(f_1-f_2)$ the "modulator".

This can be observed in a time-frequency representation:

[image]

[image]

But if we really wanted, we could make STFT represent these as separate, by increasing the window's frequency resolution:

[image]

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import windows
from ssqueezepy import stft
from ssqueezepy.visuals import imshow, plot

def cosines(freqs, N):
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
    return np.sum([np.cos(2*np.pi * f * t) for f in freqs], axis=0)

N = 2048
t = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
x1 = cosines([50, 250], N)
x2 = cosines([50, 60],  N)

Sx1, Sx2 = stft(x1), stft(x2)
stft_freqs = np.linspace(0, .5, len(Sx1)) * N

plot(t, x1, title="f1, f2 = 50, 250", show=1)
plot(t, x2, title="f1, f2 = 50, 60",  show=1)

kw = dict(abs=1, xticks=t, yticks=stft_freqs, 
          xlabel="time [sec]", ylabel="frequency [Hz]")
imshow(Sx1, **kw, title="abs(STFT) | f1, f2 = 50, 250")
imshow(Sx2, **kw, title="abs(STFT) | f1, f2 = 50, 60")

Sx2_2 = stft(x2, windows.dpss(N, 4), n_fft=2048)
stft_freqs = np.linspace(0, .5, len(Sx2_2)) * N
kw['yticks'] = stft_freqs
imshow(Sx2_2, **kw, title="abs(STFT), frequency-localized | f1, f2 = 50, 60")
kw['yticks'] = stft_freqs[:128]
imshow(Sx2_2[:128], **kw, title="frequency-zoomed (same STFT)")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Single tone signal has 1 frequency:
> $\sin(2\cdot \pi \cdot f_1)$

That's not a single tone signal. That is a constant. This is missing the time-dependency!!

You mean something like

$$s_1(t) = \sin(2\pi f_1 t).$$

In a real-valued context, that would be a single tone; in the context of complex signals (and you've been talking about OFDM before, so this is probably the context in which you want to work), this is a signal composed of *two* complex tones: one at $-f_1$, and one at $+f_1$.

> Dual tone was created by using 2 frequencies:
> $\sin(2\cdot \pi \cdot (f_1 + f_2))$

No. simply no. Even when writing this as

$$s_2(t) = \sin(2\pi(f_1+f_2)t),$$

this is just a the same as your first signal, but it's at frequency $f_s=f_1+f_2$ instead.

So, I think you really might have some of your math basics wrong; I'd love to help you, but I think you simply have a wrong definition in your head, nothing I can fix :(