# Why there are spikes in instantaneous frequency vs time plot of an analytic signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, hilbert-transform

I am working on the analytic signal concept for observing the frequency variation in the faulted phase current waveform in MATLAB/Simulink model.

In MATLAB/Simulink model, I have used analytic signal block and hilbert's transform method to calculate the real and imaginary components of the faulted phase current.

After that I have used the data for real and imaginary components of the faulted phase current to calculate the magnitude, phase, and instantaneous frequency.

When I plotted the curve between the instantaneous frequency variation vs time for the faulted phase current, I observed that there are high frequency spikes in the curve.

What can be the reason and what is this phenomena called ?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! Please add a picture of your plot so we can see it a bit more detail what you're seeing.

Comment: There's a [pretty good question regarding instantaneous frequency here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24487/calculate-and-interpret-the-instantaneous-frequency).  The $f_9$ formula is the one you wanna look at.  This will avoid the spikes you get when the principle argument of phase wraps around.

Answer (score 2):

The instantaneous frequency is the time derivative of phase. The time derivative operator is a high pass filter, so it on its own will enhance high frequency noise and attenuate lower frequencies. For example, a step change in time would become an impulse after taking a derivative.

It is possible that the spikes are from "steps" that are incorrectly introduced into the phase during processing; for example if the phase is wrapping at the $2\pi$ boundaries. I suggest reviewing a plot of the phase versus time used prior to taking the derivative and confirm if this phase should be "unwrapped" prior to the derivative operation. (unwrap is a function for doing this in Matlab, Octave and Python scipy.signal).

As a simple example consider the case below of a constant frequency, which would therefore be a ramp in phase. A small amount of noise was added to the phase which is barely visible in the plot of phase versus time, but clear in the demodulated frequency (which was done as a simple difference of phase from sample to sample).

[image: FM Demoduation]

If the phase was incorrectly "wrapped" to stay within the range of $\pm pi$, the same demodulator would produce the result as given by the plots below, with very significant negative spikes where the phase wrapping occurred. Even if we did the demodulation with a improved digital differentiator that also filtered the high frequency noise, a significant amount of these spikes would still feed through:

[image: phase wrapping]

Not to conclude that phase wrapping is the source of the spikes in the OP's specific case as this is just one obvious / common source for this to occur; any other steps in phase (from actual noise sources) would also lead to spikes in the demodulated signal.

As a side-comment: this high frequency noise enhancement is a common 'feature' in FM demodulation, and is the reason for the use of [pre-emphasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemphasis_improvement#:%7E:text=In%20FM%20broadcasting%2C%20preemphasis%20improvement,a%20preemphasis%20network%20before%20transmission.) in some FM modulation implementations.

Comment: Can you share a research paper (journal or conference paper) where this answer is written. I have to study more about it.

Comment: @SiddharthKamila These are some basic signal processing concepts so not sure I can located a research paper about this specifically- but what part confuses you? The phase wrapping or that instantaneous frequency is the time derivative of phase? Or that a time derivative is a high pass filter?

Comment: This may help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase_and_frequency and to see how the derivative is a high pass filter, review the Laplace Transform of the time derivative: The Laplace of $d/dt x(t)$ is $sX(s)$. To get the frequency response replace $s$ with $j\omega$, and thus the result is $\omega X(\omega)$.

Comment: As far as the phase wrapping itself, phase wrapping produces steps in phase (as demonstrated in my answer). A derivative of a step is an impulse: consider the case of a discrete time differentiator which estimates a derivative given as $y[n]=x[n]-x[n-1]$ and what you would get for the output of that if there was a big step in time.